# Calculate item percentage span across a vertical line that equals to 100%

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

I have a graph with an Y-axis of 8 numbers:

```
0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140%
```

The 8 numbers spread equally across a vertical line that is 100%. That means each number equals to 12,5% on the vertical line.

Lets assume I need to define a bar on this graph that equals to 52% or 125%. How would I go about calculating how much that would equal to (percentage'wise) on the vertical line?

Comment: Not sure which subject area to add for this besides "percentages" - suggestions?

Comment: The two different uses of percentages here is confusing. First you use percentages for the numbers in the array and then you seem to use it to denote the placement on the vertical line?! Can you try to clarify what you mean? (is it neccesary to use $\%$ for the numbers in the array?)

Comment: I think you may want to take the height of the 100% bar and multiply it by (52/100), or (125/100). That said, I agree with Winther that the phrasing is confusing: "140%" is also somehow "100%".

Comment: Basically imagine a graph that is XXX in height which is what I describe as 100% - left side is the 8 numbers on the Y-axis that goes from 0-140. Now I want to create a bar that equals to 52 on the Y-axis = determine how much this is percentage'wise within the 100% height canvas